# Disable a text input in an angular 2 reactive form

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have a reactive form in angular 2 which can get called through an add button for a new form or an edit button to update existing details. If the user selects the edit button the email input should be disabled. I have the code below but whenever the user selects edit, the input is not disabled. If i set disabled to be true in the addForm method and select the edit button then the email input is disabled

```js
    public addForm(event: string) : FormGroup {

            this.userForm = this.fb.group({
                firstName: ['',
                    [   Validators.required,
                        Validators.maxLength(ManageUsersConstants.maxLengthName)
                    ]],
                lastName: ['',
                    [   Validators.required,
                        Validators.maxLength(ManageUsersConstants.maxLengthName)]
                    ],
                email: [{value: '', disabled : false}],
                }),
            });
        }
  

    public editForm(event: string, editValues : any) : FormGroup {
        this.userForm = this.fb.group({
            firstName: [editValues.firstName, [
                Validators.required,
                Validators.maxLength(ManageUsersConstants.maxLengthName)]],
            lastName: [editValues.lastName,
                [   Validators.required,
                    Validators.maxLength(ManageUsersConstants.maxLengthName)]],
            email: [{value: editValues.email, disabled: true}],
        });

    }
```

Comment: It looks like you're just reassigning the form. Why not directly target the input and change that instead?

`this.userForm.get('email').disable();` (I think, haven't touched one in a little bit )

Comment: sorry how do you mean directly target the input? The html?

Comment: I mean targeting email from the FormGroup (like the code bit from my last comment)

Comment: i tried that and also set/patch but it still seems to set it to false

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In edit event add the following code `this.formGroup.controls['email'].disable() ;`

**Component.ts**

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: [{value: '', disabled : false}]      
    });  
  }  

  onEdit(){    
    this.formGroup.controls['email'].disable()   
  }
```

**HTML**

```
<form [formGroup]="formGroup" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #form>
    <div>
      <label for="dateone">Email: </label>
      <input formControlName="email" #email/>          
      <button type="button" (click)="onEdit()">edit</button>  
      </div>
</form>
```

[Stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/reactive-form-email-disable)

Comment: Quick question, i added that line of code into edit and it works, but whenever i then click on add again the input is disabled. I added this line of code in - this.userForm.controls['email'].enable(); - after the form is created but it is still disabled. I get an undefined if i add it in before the form is created

Comment: Got it working, just added a check to make sure it was not undefined, and moved it to before the form is created